# ng build creates a blank index.html

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to build my Angular project, which works with `ng serve`, but every time I try to deploy it with `ng build`, I only get a blank page.

I have already tried to modify `<base href="/">` on the `index. html` on the `dist` folder, as I already saw that most problems are due to the relative path to the content, but changing it to "./" doesn't have any effect.

What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you opened the index.html file, however it is not uncommon for the `index.html` to be empty. So if you only have the index.html file open in your browser, there will inevitably be no content there.
Modifying the `<base>`-tag will not achieve the desired goal.

To exclude errors in the code use [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io).
For this:

1. Log in to [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io)
2. Create a `new sandbox`
3. Choose the sandbox type `Vanilla`
4. Copy the files of the `dist` directory into the sandbox

If the desired content appears here, the error is on the server side.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).